# How can I force all text in a cell onto the next page in Libre Office / Open Office?

Tags: libreoffice, text

When I make a table in Libre Office, and the text in a cell is too long for the page, it splits the text across multiple pages:

[image]

How can I make any row with too much text put *all* the text on one page?

If I put lots of returns before the text, it pushes it down, but I have to do that for each cell:

[image]

[image]

I can also insert an empty row and put in enough returns to push it down:

[image]

Both these solutions have the issue of not working if I change some text above it. If I remove (or add) a line or two, it has the wrong number of lines:

[image]

[image]

I'm looking for a table wide setting that forces the text from one cell to stay on the same page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click the table. Go to Table Properties and under the Text Flow tab, uncheck "Allow row to break text across pages and columns".

[image]